# How many souls need to be harvested for Xoti's quest?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity-ii

Xoti's quest needs her to first harvest a number of souls in order to advance to the next phase. The [wiki](https://pillarsofeternity.fandom.com/wiki/The_Lantern_of_Gaun) lists 10 occasions where she can do so, but it's not specified how many are required, neither is it said whether a group is counted more towards the requirement than individuals, or if only the occasions are counted.

I might have made this quest impossible by refusing her in a few occasions.

- I "used up" the soul on the very first map because I didn't have recruited Xoti yet.
- I let her harvest only one soul on the first island, in the flooded city district.
- I refused her at the digsite on the first island (after repairing the pillar) and I refused her at the Oathbinder's Sanctum, because it was very early in the game and I mistakenly thought that letting her harvest them would leave them trapped forever and won't return them to the Wheel.

Only later did I start to realize my mistake, and now I started to wonder if I have any chance to complete her quest, having lost 3 of the 11 possible events where she can harvest souls.

Are 8 out of 11 enough to trigger the next phase of her quest, or do I have to start the game almost from the beginning?